# send soap request from Android using Ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap

i'm trying to send the following request to a webservice using ksoap. i managed to send a successfull log-in request and other requests, where it is not neccessary to send the "locale..." line. And that is exactly my problem, i have no idea how to add this line to my request. I've tried doing it as a complexType, but the result is always something like " country="de" ....  and this the webservice is not accepting such a request.
I hope someone can give me a hint.

```
<request>
                <locale country="DE" datCountryIndicator="de" language="de"/>
                <sessionID>13vb4mf66m67b</sessionID>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <constructionTimeFrom>?</constructionTimeFrom>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <constructionTimeTo>?</constructionTimeTo>
                <restriction>ALL</restriction>
             </request>
```

Comment: Are you following any tutorial..

Comment: You can find a good tutorial here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

Comment: Hey, thank you for the link @Arash but I already followed this tutorial and many others. It's not the Problem to add a PropertyInfo like the "sessionID" or "constructionTimeFrom".. it's only the line "<locale ... />" which is driving me crazy. For example i can add "<locale> country="DE" ... </locale>" but the webservice does not accept this :/

Comment: what's your webservice result error message?

Comment: Here is the Message from LogCat :SoapFault - faultcode: 'S:Server' faultstring: 'java.lang.NullPointerException' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
07-02 11:57:15.491: W/System.err(2744):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:141)
07-02 11:57:15.491: W/System.err(2744):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
07-02 11:57:15.491: W/System.err(2744):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:116)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with kSOAP2 - go right to the source.

I've found a few bugs in the version of kSOAP2 I was using (for BlackBerry & Android) and most of the time had more luck tracing the methods, rather than looking for info online.